# How to plot a stacked area plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, stacked-area-chart

I have a dataframe(df) with two columns: 'Foundation Type', which has 4 types of foundations (Shafts, Piles, Combination, Spread), and another column 'Vs30' with different values for parameter Vs30. Each row represents a bridge, with a type of foundation and a Vs30 value.

First, I create an new column 'binVs30' in df, converting each element of 'Vs30' into different bins, which has 5 different kind of ranges ([0-200],[200-400]...[800-1000]).

```
df['binVs30'] = pd.cut(df.Vs30, bins=np.arange(0, 1100, 200))
```

then, I created a stacked area plot with the code as follow:

```
color_table = pd.crosstab(df['binVs30'], df['Foundation Type'], dropna=False)
ax = color_table.plot(kind='area', figsize=(8, 8), stacked=True, rot=0)
display(ax)
plt.xlabel('')
plt.ylabel('Frequency', fontsize=12)
plt.legend(title='Foundation Type', loc='upper right')
plt.title('Column Database', fontsize='20')
plt.show()
```

[image: Resulting Picture]

The resulting picture shows some extra bins that shouldn't be there. Therefore, I had to fix the xticks by manually adding the following code:

```
locs, labels = plt.xticks()
    plt.xticks(locs, ['','0-200','','200-400','','400-600','','600-800','','800-1000'], fontsize=10, rotation=45)
```

[image: xticks-fixed Picture]

Is there a reason why Python creates those extra bins that shouldn't exist? Is that a bug that Python has? Since if I change it to a stacked bar plot, the problem just vanished. Is there a way that I could fix it by not manually adding bin code?

Also two other questions are, how to add the edgecolor for an area plot? Something like:

```
color_table.plot(kind='area', figsize=(8, 8), stacked=True, edgecolor='black', legend=None, rot=0)
```

The command edgecolor='black' doesn't work in a stacked area plot.

And, if I want to create bin for 'Vs30' like ([0-200],[200-400]...[>800]). Is there a way I can do that? Since the way I create 'binVs30' column doesn't allow me create a bin that is '>800'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of questions here. Firstly about including an open-ended bin in your `pd.cut()`. You can use `np.inf` to capture everything in the last bin and assign it a custom label. Secondly, since you're already using `matplotlib`, I'd recommend using its stacking plot directly rather than via `pandas`. Then you can use `edgecolor` argument without any issues.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data={
    "foundation" : np.random.choice(list("ABCD"), 1000),
    "binVs30"    : np.random.randint(0, 1200, 1000)
})

bins = [0, 200, 400, 600, 800, np.inf]
labels = ["0-199", "200-399", "400-599", "600-799", "800+"]

df["bins"] = pd.cut(
    df["binVs30"], bins=bins, labels=labels,
    right=False, include_lowest=True)

stack_data = pd.crosstab(df['bins'], df['foundation'], dropna=False)

stack_array = stack_data.values.T.tolist()

pal = sns.color_palette("Set1")
plt.figure(figsize=(8,4))

plt.stackplot(
    labels, stack_array, labels=list("ABCD"),
    colors=pal, alpha=0.4, edgecolor="black")

plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

[image]